# how to update a part of a form before submission

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I created a form to set up appointments. The form contains different groups: The first group is the invitee and the host, then comes the available dates. For the available dates the user should be able to add one date, then the date would add up to the list of available dates above and he can keep adding dates that way. When he is done adding dates, posting the form sends the data to the database. 
For the partial update of the form, I used jquery to send back the input date of the form to a controller that appends it in a available_dates session array:

in appointments/new.html.erb:

```
<section id="invitee, host... />
<section id="available_dates-section">
    <ol id="available-dates" >
        <%= @available_dates.each do |date| %>
            <%= render 'available_date', :date => date%>
        <% end %>
    </ol>
    <%= render 'form' %>
</section>
```

in appointments/_form.html.erb

```
<form  id="new_appointment">
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <%= date_field(:appointments, :date, class: "form-control") %>
    </div>
    <div id="add_date">
        <%= link_to "add_date", "#", remote: true %>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then, in appointments_controller.rb:

```
def new
    binding.pry # goes here after clicking on "add date" the first time instead of in add_dates
    # after session[:available_dates] is set in add_date, the flow then comes here and session[:available_dates] is now nil
    @appointment = Appointment.new
    @available_dates = session[:available_dates] || []
end

def create
    binding.pry
    params[:appointment][dates] = session[:available_dates]
    @appointment = Appointment.create_with_param(params[:appointment])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to "/appointments/show" }
        format.js # render /appointments/create.js
    end
end

def add_date
    session[:available_dates] ||= []
    session[:available_dates] << params[:appointments][:date]
    binding.pry # session[:available_dates] is correctly set
end
```

And in appointments/new.js.erb:

```
$("#add_date").on("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("coucou"); # works
 $.ajax({
    url: "/appointments/add_date",
    type: "POST",
    data: $("#new_appointment").serialize(),
    success: function(data){
        alert(data); 
     }
});
})
```

and in routes.rb, I have:

```
resources :appointments
post 'appointments/add_date', to: 'appointments#add_date'
```

After fixing a typo in routes.rb, the problem is now that the session is lost in `AppointmentsController::new` after `available_dates` is set in `AppointmentsController::add_date`.

First for some reason, the first time I click on the link, the js is not called but new is called instead. The second time I click, the js is called and `session[:available_dates]` is set in `AppointmentsController::add_date` as expected. Then however, `AppointmentsController::new` is called again and `session[:available_dates]` lost its value.

Any idea why `AppointmentsController::new` is being called like this (before & after `AppointmentsController::add_dates`)? And how can I prevent it?

Also, I do have the `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` in application.html.erb and I get this behavior even after commenting the `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` in the ApplicationController anyways.

I am very new to ruby, rails and jquery so if you have any suggestion on any other way to achieve what I am trying to do as well as suggestions on style, I'd love to read them!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:-

```
<%= link_to "add_date", "javascript:void(0);" %>
or
<%= link_to "add_date", add_date_appointments_path, remote: true %>
```

Instead of :-

```
<%= link_to "add_date", "#", remote: true %>
```

If we are not giving method_path in link and use "#" then on click on link it calls the current page url action.

Comment: The reason I put this "#" is that I don't want to use this as a link but as a trigger for javascript. In new.js.erb, I called `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the link to be used as such, or did I misunderstand it? It does go into the javascript function because I added an alert after the `event.preventDefault();` and it shows. However, trying to alert in the post success does not work.
I wanted to post to add_date. But I guess I could try with a get.

Comment: Would'nt the `javascript:void(0);` in the `link_to` replace the new.js.erb behavior to do nothing instead of posting to `/add_date` as is done in there?

Comment: For using javascript function you have to use "javascript:void(0);" in link. And add javascript code in common js file like custom.js.erb file instead of new.js.erb. Then alert will also work and no need to call event.prevendefault.